# @OnWriteError method not updating the DB record status

Tags: spring-batch

I have an itemWriter that writes items to the table. When writing, I get a ConstraintViolationException and I am using SkipPolicy to skip that Exception and i have implemented @OnWriteError method.So it works fine to catch and skip the exception and calls the @OnWriteError method inside the listener. Inside @OnWriteError method i am calling another method to mark the event as failed when there is an exception caught.

@OnWriteError

public void onWriteError(Exception exception,List items )
{

log.info("WRITE ERROR LISTENER CALLED");

Student student = items.get(items.size()-1);

studnetManager.updateStatuss(student, "FAILED);

}

public void updateStatuss(Student student, Status status)
{

Student.setStatus(status);

StudentRepository.save(Student);

}

updateStatuss() gets called successfully but the student record is not marked as FAILED.
Can anyone help me understand this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Javadoc, [ItemWriteListener#onWriteError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html#onWriteError-java.lang.Exception-java.util.List-) will be called in a transaction that is going to be rolled back.

So you need to call that code in a separate transaction (either annotate `updateStatus` with `@Transactional(propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW")` or programmatically call the transactional code using a `TransactionTemplate`).

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. That really solved my problem. But how does using @Transactional(propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW") impact performance ?